# How to iterate a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Forgive me if something about what I'm about to ask sounds stupid, I've just started with numpy and multi-dimensional arrays in Python :D

That said, I've got a 3D array of [85 x 235 x 327]. Each position holds a discrete value, and, in most cases, NaN.

First thing I'd like to do is iterate over this array and remove the NaN values, building a new array that contains only valid values.

I've tried this:

```
    for index,value in np.ndenumerate( data ):
    print "index value: " + str(index)
    print "value: " + str(value)
```

But this will only execute one pass...not really sure what `ndenumerate` does.

Also tried this:

```
indexOne = waves.shape[0]
indexTwo = waves.shape[1]
indexThree = waves.shape[2]

for i in range(indexOne):
    for j in range(indexTwo):
        for k in range(indexThree):
            a = waves[i,j,k]
            print a.data
```

And while this does iterates...taking into account that I have 6531825 points...this is going to take forever...thus, is there any built-in function to remove values from an existing array without having to iterate all the elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? That makes it sound like you just want a flat array containing only non-nan values. Or do you want the values replaced with something else?

Comment: Have you read through http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial or http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/index.html ? I think you will find it helpful.

Comment: @senderle I just want get rid of those values, having a final array with all the values, preserving the shape, if possible, otherwise a flat array.

Comment: @MrE Yeah, I did, thanks for sharing tough :)

Comment: title of question is misleading here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little on what you want the final array to look like. Here's something that literally does what you say. However, it doesn't preserve the shape. Setting up the array:

```
>>> a = numpy.linspace(0, 26, 27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
>>> a[1][0] = numpy.nan
>>> a
array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.,   5.],
        [  6.,   7.,   8.]],

       [[ nan,  nan,  nan],
        [ 12.,  13.,  14.],
        [ 15.,  16.,  17.]],

       [[ 18.,  19.,  20.],
        [ 21.,  22.,  23.],
        [ 24.,  25.,  26.]]])
```

Then you can create a mask with `isnan`:

```
>>> numpy.isnan(a)
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

And use it to index `a`:

```
>>> a[~numpy.isnan(a)]
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,  12.,  13.,
        14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,
        25.,  26.])
```

You could use a similar trick to do many other things with `nan` values. For example:

```
>>> a[numpy.isnan(a)] = 0
>>> a
array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.,   5.],
        [  6.,   7.,   8.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [ 12.,  13.,  14.],
        [ 15.,  16.,  17.]],

       [[ 18.,  19.,  20.],
        [ 21.,  22.,  23.],
        [ 24.,  25.,  26.]]])
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed answer...is this advisable with a array as big as mine? From my point of view, I don't mind losing the shape, since, if I have no values...I don't mind losing that column, really.

Comment: It's true that this produces a second boolean array of the same size as the original; two arrays with 6 million elements isn't too much to handle for most modern computers though. Still, there are a lot of `nan`-related functions in `numpy` that might help reduce memory usage if you need it. For example, you can create a "masked array" using [`numpy.ma.masked_invalid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html#numpy.ma.masked_invalid); the masked array takes up more memory, but may save memory or be more efficient in some operations.

Comment: Thanks senderle, this effectively works. Any idea on how numpy flattens the multidimensional array into a 1D one? Just wondering how many "info" I'm losing in the process :D

Answer (score 1):

[`nan_to_num`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) does exactly what you want:

> Replace nan with zero and inf with finite numbers.
>
> Returns an array or scalar replacing Not a Number (NaN) with zero,
>   (positive) infinity with a very large number and negative infinity
>   with a very small (or negative) number.

Use it like:

```
x = np.nan_to_num(x)
```